# simple car start/stop sim issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've literally just begun learning python, starting with some lengthy youtube tutorials. One tutorial wanted me to create a sim/game of starting and stopping a car. My code is *very* similar to the solution. I'm not sure what the problem is. The specific issue is the program fails to return the print function for when the car is *already* started or stopped--it just reiterates the start/stop print as if the boolean code to indicate whether the car is on or off at present doesn't exist.

```
start = input('Enter "help" to see instructions: ').lower()

if start == 'help':
    started = False
    user_input = input("start - start the car\nstop - stop the car\nquit - exist program\n").lower()
    while True:
        if user_input == "start":
            if started:
                print("The car is already on.\n") #so if i enter start two times in a row, the second time it should print "The car is already on."
            else:
                started = True
                print("The car has started. Now what?\n")
        elif user_input == "stop":
            if not started:
                print("The car is already stopped.\n")
            else:
                started = False
                print("The car has stopped. Now what?\n") #if this is the first command entered after "help", it should be printing "The car is already stopped." but doesn't do that.
        elif user_input == 'quit':
            break
else:
    print("This is not a valid command.")
```

Comment: Try move the `user_input = input("start -....` inside the while loop.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work :(

Comment: See my code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep taking user_input inside the while loop. Just move user_input inside the while loop.

```
start = input('Enter "help" to see instructions: ').lower()

if start == 'help':
    started = False

    while True:
        user_input = input("start - start the car\nstop - stop the car\nquit - exist program\n").lower()
        if user_input == "start":
            if started:
                print("The car is already on.\n") #so if i enter start two times in a row, the second time it should print "The car is already on."
            else:
                started = True
                print("The car has started. Now what?\n")
        elif user_input == "stop":
            if not started:
                print("The car is already stopped.\n")
            else:
                started = False
                print("The car has stopped. Now what?\n") #if this is the first command entered after "help", it should be printing "The car is already stopped." but doesn't do that.
        elif user_input == 'quit':
            break
else:
    print("This is not a valid command.")
```

And here is the output:

```
[evaluate untitlewerwd-1.py]
Enter "help" to see instructions: help
start - start the car
stop - stop the car
quit - exist program
start
The car has started. Now what?

start - start the car
stop - stop the car
quit - exist program
start
The car is already on.

start - start the car
stop - stop the car
quit - exist program
stop
The car has stopped. Now what?

start - start the car
stop - stop the car
quit - exist program
stop
The car is already stopped.

start - start the car
stop - stop the car
quit - exist program
stop
The car is already stopped.

start - start the car
stop - stop the car
quit - exist program
quit
```

Comment: weird. it didnt work the first time i ran it. i probably forgot to quit from the original program I'm guessing. Thanks for you help. I guess if the user_input statement is not in the while loop, it doesn't get updated. I should have thought of that. Thank you.